# Why doesn't Javascript work on XML if it's external

Tags: javascript, xml

I did some manipulation with an XML database through Javascript. XML was within the HTML code and it worked fine, but when I wanted to use XLST, I had to make XML external. Upon doing so, Javascript lost all it's function, even though the ID of the XML file which I used to call it in a function remained the same.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: It's because of the same-origin policy, I'd wager. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: What do you mean by external? How are you working with the "external" document? You need to show details.

Answer (score 1):

You need some intermediate device to go between the JavaScript and XML file (server-side code of some fashion most-likely). JavaScript cannot directly manage flat files (which is what the "XML database" you reference is).

Work-flow would be in the following [pseudo-]pattern:

1. Use server to read (and render) XML to the browser.
2. Use JavaScript to manipulate the XML (via some UI like dialogs, lists, or just plain functionality).
3. Use JavaScript to pass the new XML format back to the server for storing.

if you already have a go-between, make sure you're on the same domain name when making calls to and from the server. As a commenter pointed out, JavaScript cannot go between domain levels natively; Instead you'd have to use either something like JSONP or setup the `Access-Control-*` headers on the remote server,